# modify ProgressDialog Message size and Message color

Tags: android

i have a ProgressDialog:

```
pBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
        ((TextView) pBar.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setText("dfdf");
        pBar.setTitle(title);
        pBar.setMessage(msg);
        pBar.setProgressStyle(style);
        pBar.setProgress(100);
```

but i want to modify the message text size and color,can you give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

You can set a contentView to a progress dialog i think, can't you?

Regards,